# windows vista bsod

Tags: windows, windows-vista, bsod

I had to reinstall Vista about a two months ago due to machine unable to boot-up properly.
Reinstalled my software apps. A few weeks ago got the BSOD. Again I got it today. 
Now I am using the windows debugger oh goody!

My question is could this be a hardware problem with the prior history of issues I have been having with this machine...or could it be a resident device driver used by Windows?

### Below is a snippet of the debug info from the debugger:

```
AD_POOL_CALLER (c2)
The current thread is making a bad pool request.  Typically this is at a bad IRQL level or double freeing the same allocation, etc.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000007, Attempt to free pool which was already freed
Arg2: 000000000000110b, (reserved)
Arg3: 000000008c5800c1, Memory contents of the pool block
Arg4: fffffa6004278094, Address of the block of pool being deallocated
```

### Debugging Details:

```
BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc2_7

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80001b8ef98 to fffff80001aaf390
```

Answer (score 2):

"could this be a hardware problem", "or could it be a resident device driver used by Windows?"

Based on the info given, the answer is "Yes". :)

To start diagnosing, update your drivers, and [test your RAM](http://www.memtest.org).

Comment: I did use the memory utility that comes with the machine which I feel even though it passed it may not be rigorous enough. I will get a good memory test utility and update my windows drivers.
Thanks for the input.

Comment: Usually when we test RAM (to determine good or bad for (re)use) we run Memtest86+ against them for 48-72 hours (non stop).  Over the years I've had plenty of bad addresses show up on the 2nd and 3rd day of testing.